# Mutlisite in wordpress is not working

Tags: theme-development, multisite

I have created wordpress multi-site.

but when i tried open example.com/au. it gives me server 404 error. I already enable mod_rewrite and start the apache service. I am using ubuntu14.0 and my root directory is /var/www.

wp-config.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'eplate.cloudapp.net');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

and .htacess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Is there is any settings i need to change on sever ?

Thanks

Comment: this is working fine on local

Comment: Did you export the database from local to web? If so, have you changed all references to the local URL in `wp-config.php` and in the DB?

Comment: No, i installed fresh on server.. Is there is server settings i need to change?

Comment: If it's a fresh install it should be fine, it's just that if you have a working local copy whcih to export to your server on you would need to change the references to the local URL.